# How to scrape data with filters from the website when the URL doesn't change?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I've scraped data from [this list](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/wordlists/oxford3000-5000) in R, however it doesn't include the website filters (**List = Oxford 3000 and CEFR level = A1**) that I had applied, and there aren't variables as far as I can see which I can use to filter the data in R.

Is there some other way I can get just the data I want? The URL doesn't appear to change with filtering.

Here is my code:

```
url <- "https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/wordlists/oxford3000-5000" 

url %>%
  map(. %>%
    read_html() %>%
      html_nodes(".belong-to , .pos , a") %>%
      html_text()
  ) %>%
  unlist() -> ox3ka1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select only the words with filter `a1` we can do the following,

```
df = 'https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/wordlists/oxford3000-5000' %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes('.top-g') %>% html_nodes( "li[data-ox5000 = 'a1']") %>% html_text()

head(df)
[1] "   a   indefinite articlea1      " "   about   adverba1      "         "   about   prepositiona1      "    "   above   adverba1      "        
[5] "   above   prepositiona1      "    "   across   adverba1      "
```

Further reference,
[How do I use html_nodes to select nodes with "attribute = x" in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59198803/how-do-i-use-html-nodes-to-select-nodes-with-attribute-x-in-r)